# A C# parser for Web Links (RFC 5988)

Tags: c#, hyperlink, rfc

Anyone created an open source C# parser for Web Links HTTP "Link" header?
See:
 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988.

Example:

```
Link: <http://example.com/TheBook/chapter2>; rel="previous"; title="previous chapter"
```

Thanks.

**Update**: Ended up creating my own parser: https://github.com/JornWildt/Ramone/blob/master/Ramone/Utility/WebLinkParser.cs. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ended up creating my own parser: https://github.com/JornWildt/Ramone/blob/master/Ramone/Utility/WebLinkParser.cs. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension method I've used:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseLinksHeader(
    this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var links = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    response.Headers.TryGetValues("link", out var headers);
    if (headers == null) return links;

    var matches = Regex.Matches(
        headers.First(),
        @"<(?<url>[^>]*)>;\s+rel=""(?<link>\w+)\""");
    
    foreach(Match m in matches)
        links.Add(m.Groups["link"].Value, m.Groups["url"].Value);

    return links;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Take the [HTML Agility Pac](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)k and use the right

> SelectNodes

query.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc =web.Load(url);
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@Link]"))
            {
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but, no, that's not what I am asking for. I am referring to the HTTP protocol level "Link" header as described in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988.

Comment: How are you getting your HTML documents?  If it is a WebResponse, there is the Headers enumaration which should contain the LINK.

Comment: No problem getting the string from the HTTP headers. The problem is parsing the content of the string - splitting it into parts consisting of URL, rel-type, title and more.